# How to Set an existing ECS cluster to a compute environment in AWS Batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, solution, amazon-ecs

I have an `ECS cluster` running in my environment and it is configured with tasks, repositories and services and autoscaling.

I am discovering the `AWS Batch` service and when I create a new `compute environment` a new cluster is being added to the `ECS` service.
 I want to know how to set a `compute environment` to my already existing cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my knowledge (spent half of day, studying documentation and forums), that's impossible. `computeEnvironments`'s `ecsClusterArn` is assigned immediately after creation of compute environment, and cannot be changed.

Interesting is that Batch somehow modifies `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` on newly created instances in managed CE:

`... // config from my AMI
ECS_CLUSTER=my_cluster_name
... // 
ECS_CLUSTER={ENVIRONMENT NAME HERE}_Batch_{RANDOM UUID HERE}
ECS_DISABLE_IMAGE_CLEANUP=false
ECS_ENGINE_TASK_CLEANUP_WAIT_DURATION=2m
ECS_IMAGE_CLEANUP_INTERVAL=10m
ECS_IMAGE_MINIMUM_CLEANUP_AGE=10m
ECS_NUM_IMAGES_DELETE_PER_CYCLE=5
ECS_RESERVED_MEMORY=32
ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS=["json-file","awslogs"]`

, and first `ECS_CLUSTER` is wiped with second. That looks like some predefined `user-data`, but I couldn't find where that can be changed either.

However, probably you can achieve original goal with reversed approach -- create *unmanaged* CE, and loop over instances you want to be in that CE, change `ECS_CLUSTER` in `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` to `$that_autogenerated_CE_arn`, restart `ecs-agent` (or relevant docker, if that's not Amazon Linux). Now your containers belong to another cluster, and only difference is in cluster's name.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite an old question and that it's not exactly the same case, but I was struggling with something similar, so it might be helpful to someone. In my case Batch was overwriting my `ECS_DISABLE_IMAGE_CLEANUP` setting, causing my special dedicated super-high-priority Job Queue (with its Compute Environment) lose its images, causing an annoying delay when they had to be pulled again.

To address this, I had to create a Launch Template (in EC2 console), which had everything set as "don't change", and some extra "user data" (at the end of the Advanced section):

```
 MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==MYBOUNDARY=="

--==MYBOUNDARY==
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"

#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_DISABLE_IMAGE_CLEANUP=true>>/etc/ecs/ecs.config 

--==MYBOUNDARY==--
```

Then I had to recreate the Compute Environment as to use this Launch Template, which cause this extra line to be added to the `ecs.config` file and overwrite the Batch setting. Maybe it will work for the cluster, too!