# How do I tag the ECS Cluster that's automatically created by an AWS Batch Compute Environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I am trying to deploy a Batch Compute Environment in a heavily restricted AWS environment. For billing purposes, all resources created need to be tagged (e.g. `billTo: billId`), and if I try to create a resource without this tag I am blocked by an explicit deny. When the Batch Compute Environment tries to create an ECS Cluster, I get the following error because it does not pass tags to it.

```
User: arn:aws:sts::<accountId>:assumed-role/<roleName> is not authorized to perform ecs:CreateCluster on resource: * with an explicit deny
```

There are two places to specify tags when creating a Batch Compute Environment (tag the compute environment and tag the EC2 resources used by the compute environment). I tried adding the `billTo` tag in both places but still hit the same error.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get Batch to tag the ECS Cluster it tries to create when making a new Batch Compute Environment?

*Note: I also tried figuring out how to pass an existing ECS Cluster, but this is not possible ([How to Set an existing ECS cluster to a compute environment in AWS Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389717/how-to-set-an-existing-ecs-cluster-to-a-compute-environment-in-aws-batch))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2021-07-15, AWS does not provide a way to tag the ECS Cluster automatically made by the Batch Compute Environment. The solution is to

1. Get in contact with the system administrators
2. Have them lift the SCP (service control policy) causing the explicit deny for a short window
3. Create the Batch Compute Environment and add the tag to the ECS Cluster
4. Have the system administrators put the SCP back in place
5. Hope you don't have to redeploy and bug the system administrators again

Hopefully AWS will fix this issue and allow the ECS Cluster to be tagged by the Batch Compute Environment.